# Expression Engine 1.x Page deletion db query

Tags: query

Does any one know of a custom query to extract when a page was deleted in Expression engine 1.x. We have a couple pages that just disappeared and the higher ups wants answers. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ExpressionEngine does not log entry creation/deletion unfortunately - only user logins, and higher-level admin actions (such as creating/deleting channels, fields, and members), which can be found under **Admin → Utilities → View Control Panel Log**.

So no way to know who deleted your page (without, you know, just asking around).